# Nested NG Repeating

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object (see below) which represents Categories and inside Categories there are Products.

Having read bout ng-repeat it seems I need to create an ng-repeat to render the HTML blocks for each category, but also for each of the products within the category there is a similar html template that repeats. Im guessing this is some kind of nested process can anyone assist?

Also as Im using bootstrap accordion you can see my html relies on a unique name each time eg collapse-one, collapse-two. Can iteration of numbers be included to it can render collapse-1, collapse-2 etc

Thanks in advance

```
{
"Data": [
    {
        "Category": {
            "Key": 1,
            "Value": "Category Title"
        },
        "ProfileOptions": [
            {
                "Key": 2129,
                "Value": "Product 1",
                "EditableByUser": true
            },
            {
                "Key": 3363,
                "Value": "Product 2",
                "EditableByUser": true
            },
            {
                "Key": 2164,
                "Value": "Product 3",
                "EditableByUser": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Category": {
            "Key": 2,
            "Value": "Category Title"
        },
        "ProfileOptions": [
            {
                "Key": 2129,
                "Value": "Product 1",
                "EditableByUser": true
            },
            {
                "Key": 3363,
                "Value": "Product 2",
                "EditableByUser": true
            },
            {
                "Key": 2164,
                "Value": "Product 3",
                "EditableByUser": true
            }
        ]
    }
],
"Success": true
}
```

The HTML is as below

```
<div class="panel-group accordion" id="products-accordion">

  <!-- CATEGORY REPEATER -->
  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="category in businessData">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#products-accordion" href="#collapseOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <span class="blcMarker"></span>{{category.Value}}
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <!-- PRODUCTS REPEATER -->
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4" ng-repeat="product in businessData.categories">
          <label><input type="checkbox" id="chk-1" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a nested `ng-repeat` where the nested one uses a variable of the first repeated element:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in categories">
    {{ cat.name }}
    <ul>
        <!-- You can use 'cat' here -->
        <li ng-repeat="product in cat.products">
            {{ product.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div
```

So you can just change your

`ng-repeat="product in businessData.categories"`

To

`ng-repeat="product in category"`

Where `category` is the same as the variable in the first `ng-repeat` (`category in businessData`)

Comment: HI, I am having some issues implementing your suggestion. I am using $scope.businessData = data

and have achieved slight success on the parent div structure (categories) by ng-repeat="cat in businessData" then writing the title as {{cat.Category.Value}}

but i am having issues now with products - looking at the JSON model, the products arent a child of categories so how can I target them? They are in the node: ProfileOptions

Comment: I think ive resolved it - my sub item I have used: product in cat.ProfileOptions then reference {{product.Value}}. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this exact thing in my last project. This is how i accomplished it.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="researchArea in researchAreas track by $index">
        <span class="title">{{ researchArea.name }}</span>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="category in researchArea.categories track by $index">
                <span class="title">{{ category.name }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```